# How can I run multiple Node App in a Github Actions?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github-actions

This is my actions

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI/CD Akper Bina Insan - Live

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Install Yarn
      run: npm install -g yarn
    - name: Build UI - Akper Bina Insan
      working-directory: ./ui
      run: yarn && yarn build && yarn start
    - name: Build Backend Service - Akper Bina Insan
      working-directory: ./be
      run: yarn && yarn build && yarn prod
```

After it finished with the first run, it don't go continue with the second run. Even though the server is ready. I waited for 5 minutes then I stopped since I don't want to waste time.

How can I make it run for the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub actions are a tool for CI/CD and **not** for hosting (running) your application.

In the given workflows, you `build` an then `run` your UI application. The run command is a blocking process - e.g. your workflow will remain blocked because you have started your UI application. You **should not** do that in workflows.

Use GitHub Action for build and test, but not for hosting.

Comment: Hi Denis, thank you for your respon.How about the self-host runner? I saw a couple of youtuber do that to push the changes to a vps

Comment: This answer's unhhelpful. User wasn't saying they need to host their application. But often, you do need to start a service for integration testing.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an ending  `&` to the node command solved this for my use-case

```
run: yarn && yarn build && yarn start &
```

or

```
run: | 
  yarn
  yarn build
  yarn start &
```

Using `&` in the end of a command, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell, therefore running the first `yarn start` won't be blocking your next step in the workflow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why this may resolve the OP’s issue.